# making a post request using python requests library for a web app that uses Bearer Token

Tags: python, python-3.x, authentication, http-post, bearer-token

I'm trying to make a POST requst using python requests library to a website that authenticate using Bearer token. Here's my code:

```
sess = requests.session()
post_url = 'someURL'
payload = {'username': 'myusername',
           'password': 'mypassword'}
post_header = {'Authentication': f'Bearer {token_value}'}    
r = sess.post(url_post, data=payload, headers=post_header)

with open('index.html', 'w', encoding="utf-8") as f:
    f.write(r.text)
```

In response I get the login page again with status_code 200.
I also tried the **auth** parameter in post function but none of them worked.
anyone knows what should i do?

Comment: Did you check `{token_value}` replaced with its original value?

Comment: of course yes. thanks for attention

Comment: Is the POST url same as login page url? (1) IF so, server must have been designed to differentiate GET and POST request of same URL and it is either server error that sends page html instead of validating credentials or it may be designed to send login page if the token is wrong or expired. so check your token validity and check server. (2) IF NOT so, it is most probably the later case.

Comment: (1)No, the POST url is different from the login page url

Comment: something like this:
login page url: **https://example.com/**
POST url: **https://example.com/signin**

Comment: Can you try `Authorization` instead of `Authentication` in post header

Comment: I tried. same result

Comment: Please try once without any payload, just with headers. If still not working, you should check server documentation about the format they expect.

Comment: @liju thanks for your help. in response header the server is **kestrel** and powered by ASP.NET. any idea how can i have some documentation on that?

Comment: [this](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/aspnet/jwt-validation-and-authorization-in-asp-net-core/) will help. there is a sample request mentioned in the page that uses GET without any payload but with header `Authorization` and with bearer as small 'b'. Please try that as well.. you can see in sample response it sends 'kestrel'